# Why cant I pass an objects string value into a API sorting function in React?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, sorting, filter

I am trying to inject the value of {clickedYear} into my filter function so that I can use the information dynamically.

How can I pull the value from the {clickedYear} so that the response from the API is sorted properly within an array? On the console.log the information is there in a string but it's not working within the function. The sorting doesn't work and returns an empty array...

here is my code:

```
const InformationBoxLayout = ({ clickedYear }) => {
    const [activeYear, setActiveYear] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
        axios
            .get('http://www.mocky.io/v2/5ea446a43000005900ce2ca3')
            .then((response) =>
                setActiveYear(
                    response.data.timelineInfo.filter(
                        (item) => item.year === { clickedYear }
                    )
                )
            );
    }, []);

return (...some code...)
```

Comment: `activeYear` is not an array, and you have not shared any code showing what `clickedYear` type could be.

Comment: @eavichay - How do you know `activeYear` isn't an array? I know the name doesn't suggest it, but all the code does.

Comment: @ dgozen - Do you really want `activeYear` to be an array? You *seem* to, from the `useState` initializer (`[]`) and the fact you're passing an array into `setActiveYear`, it just seems odd, I'd expect it to be `activeYears` plural and not to filter to a single year.

Comment: `activeYear` as appears in the JSON is *not* an array. The code compares `clickedYear` with `item.year`, but the state is of an Array. I assume more code will be helpful to understand the problem.

Comment: JSON file has several objects with the same year key value. That is why I try to pull them all into the same array. For example: by the clickedYear being 2019, I would return an array with couple of objects. I will render them out at the return later in the code

Comment: @eavichay - The code is filtering `timelineInfo`. `timelineInfo` in the JSON **is** an array (of objects with, amongst other things, a `year` property). The `filter` line is just fine other than the issue I point out in my answer.

Comment: setActiveYear(response.data.timelineInfo.filter((item) => item.year === '2009')) works perfect but its not dynamic... which is why I am trying to get the props clickedYear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `{}` around `clickedYear` when you're not in a JSX expression, which you aren't in the `filter` callback. So:

```
setActiveYear(
    response.data.timelineInfo.filter(
        (item) => item.year === clickedYear
// −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^^^^^^^^
    )
)
```

The reason it wasn't working is that `{ clickedYear }` is an object literal creating an object with a `clickedYear` property (it's shorthand property notation for `{ clickedYear: clickedYear }`). An object will never be `===` a string (I see in the JSON that `year` is a string). Also ensure that `clickedYear` is a string, not a number, since again you're using `===` which will never be true for different types.

A second thing you need to do is pass `clickedYear` as a dependency to your `useEffect` hook, since you use its value within it:

```
useEffect(() => {
    axios
        .get('http://www.mocky.io/v2/5ea446a43000005900ce2ca3')
        .then((response) =>
            setActiveYear(
                response.data.timelineInfo.filter(
                    (item) => item.year === clickedYear
// −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^^^^^^^
                )
            )
        );
}, [clickedYear]);
// ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Without that dependency, your effect callback will only be triggered once. With it, it will be triggered each time `clickedYear` changes.

---

Side note: If you like, you can use destructuring in the `filter` callback:

```
setActiveYear(
    response.data.timelineInfo.filter(
        ({year}) => year === clickedYear
// −−−−−−^^^^^^−−−−−^^^^
    )
)
```

Comment: Hey TJ I fixed the suggestion according to your syntax but I am still returning an empty array once setactiveyear() is triggered... Any ideas as to what I am missing?

Comment: @dgozen - You've checked the type of `clickedYear` as suggested above? It's a string?

Comment: Thanks after the UseEffect fix it worked! thank you so much!